# JFXTextField is not a valid type. Erro ao iniciar o aplicativo em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estou utilizando uma lib em JavaFX para estilização, e uma das estilizações que estou utilizando é o JFXTextField, porém, ao compilar o aplicativo, eu me deparo com este erro:

> JFXTextField is not a valid type

Qual a solução? Grato.

Comment: Isso é um erro de compilação. Você está utilizando JFoenix? Se sim, você colocou o `import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;`?

Comment: Boa noite Victor, isso mesmo, estou utilizando o JFoenix, e realmente este era o problema, apesar de ter baixado o .jar, precisei realizar este import, Obrigado!!.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acho que você poderia publicar uma resposta para essa pergunta, já que o seu comentário resolveu o problema.

Comment: @FagnerFonseca Feito.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, você está ussando o [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/).

Isso é um erro de compilação. Você esqueceu de colocar isso:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
```